# Unable to Modify Navigation Bar Color Using TintColor

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, tintcolor

Here is the source code for BrowserViewController.m: http://pastebin.com/w282kRm6

As you can see, in many different places I have attempted to implement the code correctly using `self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];`, but nothing has managed to work.

Comment: That's a lot of code... at no point is it clear if you actually _have_ a navigation controller. Is your view controller being displayed as part of a navigation controller? Have you tried logging the navigation controller to see what it's value is at the points you are setting the tint colour?

Comment: @jrturton No I haven't tried yet, are you suggesting that it's just a Navigation Bar without the Navigation Controller?

Comment: Yes. Try the logging or debugging. You at one point create and add a navigation bar, then set the tint colour on the navigation controllers navigation bar. Is your view controller actually part of a navigation stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.56 green:0.69 blue:0.71 alpha:1.0];`

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
[navController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0
                                                              green:51.0/255.0
                                                               blue:102.0/255.0
                                                              alpha:1.0]];
 [navController.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
```

You can change green, blue,red.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but still no luck :(